# Identity Column SQL skip zero

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [T_Manufacture](
[ManufactureID] [int] IDENTITY(-2147483648,1) NOT NULL,
[Manufacture] [varchar](25) NULL,
[ManufactureDescription] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

As we can see that the `ManufactureID` is identity column which is start from `-2147483648`. So if the identity reach -1 then the next record shoud be `0 (zero)`. Is it possible to skip this record? I mean, I don't wanna have an ID with value `zero`.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: is there any specific reason you are starting ID as `-ve`? if you want large set of ID, instead of `int` you can use `bigint`

Comment: Agree, I can use `bigint` for large set of data. There's no specific reason, but we know that minimum value of `int` is -2147483648.

Comment: yes, you are right regards to the fact of minimum value of `int` but question is when you have a right and appropriate approach, why to make it tricky?

Comment: Well, it's not tricky. It makes me curious. If there's no answer how to skip the zero int, then I'll use `bigint` as a solution.

Comment: If your code is already architected to deal with intermittent errors and perform retries then you can just add a `CHECK` constraint to the table that disallows the zero value and force the retry to occur. Since IDENTITY doesn't interact with transactions, the attempt to use it will still cause the identity value to be incremented past the 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an elaboration on Deepak's comment.

Why would anyone use negative numbers for an id column?  And, if you are concerned about having 2 billion values, then you should be concerned about 4 billion and use a `bigint`:

```
CREATE TABLE T_Manufacture (
    ManufactureID bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,  -- might as well declare it
    Manufacture varchar(25),
    ManufactureDescription varchar(50)
);
```

This is the simplest way to solve your problem and to ensure that the table can grow as large as you want.

In other words, the right way to "skip" an particular value is to start the identity enumeration *after* that value.  Or, if you really wanted:

```
CREATE TABLE T_Manufacture (
    ManufactureID int IDENTITY(-1, -1) PRIMARY KEY,  -- might as well declare it
    Manufacture varchar(25),
    ManufactureDescription varchar(50)
);
```

But once again, negative ids seem absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this with a trigger...

```
CREATE TRIGGER SkipZeroManufacture ON T_Manufacture AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 'zero record inserted' FROM inserted AS I WHERE I.ManufactureID = 0)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO T_Manufacture (
            Manufacture,
            ManufactureDescription)
        SELECT
            I.Manufacture,
            I.ManufactureDescription
        FROM
            inserted AS I
        WHERE
            i.ManufactureID = 0

        DELETE T_Manufacture WHERE ManufactureID = 0

    END

END
```

Although this is an awful idea since it will be triggered on each insert, only check for one value and will need maintenance for new or updated columns. It will also switch the 0 ID'd record with another ID.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer,,, but it seems that 'triggered on each insert' is not really good idea. Anyway, this approach so tricky... :)